# How do you use the label statement in java?

Tags: java, break

According to the java book I am reading right now, you can use labels with the following types of statements:

- A code block defined using {}
- All looping statements (for, enhanced for, while, do-while)
- Conditional constructs (if and switch)
- Expressions
- Assignments
- return statements
- try blocks
- throw statements

I understand how to use them with constructs that have curly braces but what are some useful examples of using them with the other kind of statements, like expressions, assignments, return statements and throw statements?

Comment: IMHO "labels" should be avoided - if you find yourself in a situation you think you need to labels, then your design is wrong and you should go back and rethink it until you don't see the need for labels

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am preparing for the oracle certified associate exam, it doesn't care about best practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you use the label statement in Java?

It isn't a statement. It is an optional attribute of an executable statement.

> According to the java book I am reading right now, you can use labels with the following types of statements ...

Your book is wrong. According to the [Java Language Specification #14.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7), *any* statement can have a label. However they can only be *referenced* by `break` statements, which in turn can only appear inside `switch, while, do,` or `for` statements (#14.15), or by `continue` statements, which in turn can only appear inside `while, do,` or `for` statements (#14.15).

> what are some useful examples of using them with the other kind of statements, like expressions, assignments, return statements and throw statements?

There aren't any.

Comment: Any statement can have a label? My book says declarations can't have a label, I think they are statements, too.

Comment: @Wow They aren't statements, but admittedly that's not obvious knowledge.

Comment: @Wow No, they are declarations. JLS #14.7: 'Statements may have label prefixes.'

Comment: @EJP why did they allow labels for any kind of statement when they can only be referenced from switch and loops?

Comment: @Wow Not being James Gosling I can't answer that definitively, but it would certainly make writing the parser a lot easier to do it this way: in fact trying to restrict it in the parser would be almost impossible: you would have to introduce a semantic rule.

Comment: @user207421 labeled break statements can appear only in an if-statement too like for instance in a nested if-statement. So, I think your statement "which in turn can only appear inside switch, while, do, or for statements (#14.15)" seems slightly incorrect. That would be only for break without a label.

Answer (score 0):

In a nested loop, for example, if you create a label for the outer loop, you can use a label statement to break out of the outer loop even if you are currently inside the inner loop. Look at my example.

```
OUTER_LOOP: for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
             System.out.print(i + " ");
    INNER_LOOP: for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                 System.out.print(j);
                 break OUTER_LOOP;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no such thing as a useful example of label use. Apparently you are well aware of useless examples.

There is no such thing as a label use that add anything new compared to not have the label at all, when the label is not before a code block. The language chose to allow it, but using this permission is without visible effects.

Comment: Your first paragraph is unconditional. Your second paragraph introduces a condition. Which is it?

Comment: @EJP The second paragraph gives up on the notion of usefulness, and concentrates on whether having a label changes anything at all, like adding a potential mechanism regardless of the usefulness of such a mechanism. Labels typically introduce the mechanism of named breaks and continues. But that's only in front of blocks of code.

Comment: You don't consider `break <identifier>` and `continue <identifier>` useful?

Comment: @EJP no. Who does?

Comment: I do, and so do the [authors of the JLS and `java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#d5e21356), for a start. Three counterexamples which refute your first paragraph.

Comment: @EJP that code example can easily be rewritten to be much clearer and just as efficient in modern Java environment, without a label.

Comment: Don't tell me, tell the authors of the JLS and `java.lang.String`. You can't just equate your own personal preferences with universal laws.

Comment: @EJP if it's not broken, don't fix it. It made sense in the ancient days of Java to avoid private method calls, and there is little sense changing it for readability and no other reason. I have nothing to say to them on the matter.

Comment: Then you should have nothing to say to SO readers on the matte either. You are posting opinion as fact.